# send() not sending data to clients, socket programming

Tags: c, sockets, client, send

I am trying to create a server that connects to multiple clients. Basically, what I want to do not is to send to all the clients a prompt whenever someone new connects to the server. However, the send() command does not send the data.:( I wonder what's wrong with the code.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
int listenfd,connfd;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
socklen_t len = sizeof(cliaddr);
char cli_ip[32];
char mesg[1024];
char broadcast[500];
int maxconn,counter = 0;
//  struct addrinfo hints, *ai, *p;

socklen_t addrlen;
fd_set master;
fd_set read_fds;
int fdmax;
int yes = 1;
int i, j;
char  remoteIP[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

FD_ZERO(&master);
FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
listenfd = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
servaddr.sin_port = htons(54321);
setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));

if(bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 ){
    perror(NULL);
    exit(1);
}
maxconn = 2;
if((listen(listenfd,5)) == -1){
    perror("listen");
    exit(2);
}
FD_SET(listenfd, &master);
fdmax = listenfd;
while(1){
    read_fds = master;
    if((select(fdmax + 1,&read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL )) == -1){
        perror("select");
        exit(3);
    }
    for(i = 0; i <= fdmax; i++){
        if(FD_ISSET(i, &master)){
            if(i = listenfd){
                if(counter<= maxconn){
                    addrlen = sizeof(cliaddr);
                    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &addrlen);
                    counter++;
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET,(struct in_addr *)&cliaddr.sin_addr, cli_ip, sizeof(cli_ip));
                    if(connfd == -1){
                        perror("accept");
                        exit(4);
                    }else{
                        FD_SET(connfd, &master);
                        if(connfd > fdmax)
                            fdmax = connfd;
                        sprintf(broadcast,"Player %d from %s has connected.\n",connfd, cli_ip);
                        for(j = i+ 1; j <= connfd; j++){
                            if(FD_ISSET(j, &master)){
/*somehow this doesn't work :(*/    if((send(j, broadcast, sizeof(broadcast), 0))){
                                    perror("send");
                                    exit(5);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        printf("%s,%d\n",broadcast,counter);
                        printf("%d,%d\n",i,fdmax);
                        break;
                    }
                }else{
                    printf("server full\n");
                    close(connfd);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

As you can see this code is a little bit similar to that in Beej's guide. So why does the client/s do not receive the broadcast?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Well there is no error message, the clients are not just printing "Player ... from ... has connected". So I deduced that the server must somehow NOT be sending the data even though i tested and the code enters that "for" loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is your exact problem but this won't work as you expect.

```
if ((send(j,  broadcast,  sizeof(broadcast),  0)))
{
    perror("send");
    exit(5);
}
```

`send` is going to return the number of bytes sent or -1 on error and this is going to evaluate to true for anything other than 0 so you should be at least be seeing the output of `perror` even if it misleading because it is just some random value in errno because `send` didn't actually fail, followed by program termination.

And you don't want to send `sizeof(broadcast)` which will be the whole 500 bytes, most of which is random junk, but `strlen(broadcast)`.